# React.js: How to use isLength in validator library?

Tags: reactjs

I'm using `validator` library for my password validation

I'm trying to use each validator for custom use

However, I'm having problem when using `isLength` validator to see if max length is invalid

```
validator.isLength(e.target.value [, options])
```

`e.target.value` is my string from the Textfield

According to the documentation, `options` is an object which defaults to {min:0, max: undefined}. Note: this function takes into account surrogate pairs.

How do I declare the maximum possible length with that syntax?

`validator.isLength(e.target.value [0, 5])` is not working

Should I create an object first? With {"min":"0","max":"5"}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, as per the doc , it should look like this

```
validator.isLength(e.target.value , {min:0, max: 5})
```